# Updating multiple divs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am using the following code to update a `div`

```
echo $this->Js->link($station["Company"]["name"], 
                        array('action' => 'station_users','company_id'=>$station["Company"]["id"]), 
                        array('id'=>'team_member'.$x,  'update' => '#myDIV')
                    );
```

But now I have a need to update multiple divs. How do I go about it? I want to update multiple divs by clicking on that link.

Comment: Please edit your question to only include the tag relevant to the version of CakePHP you're using, It may help the others give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use jQuery instead of JsHelper. JsHelper will also render it as jQuery script.

You can add the following type of code in your view in a script block.

```
jQuery("#id").bind('click', function(event) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend : function(XMLHttpRequest) {
            jQuery("#sending").show();
        },
        data : jQuery("#id").closest("form").serialize(),
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data, textStatus) {
            updateMultipleDivs(data, textStatus);
        },
        type : "post",
        url : "\/AppName\/ControllerName\/Method"
    });
    return false;
});
function updateMultipleDivs(data, textStatus) {
    jQuery('#Div1toUpdate').before(data);
    jQuery("#Div2toUpdate").hide();
}
```